# Move main menu to left to avoid some custom elements overlapping

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, woocommerce, cart

I made some customization on [my site](http://celularesbaratos.mx/), but noticed one issue that i cant resolve. Because main menu have fixed width, now main menu, and search and cart icons are overlapping with main menu, making contact page unaccessible. So how to make main menu, a little to left, so contact page will be usable ?

This is CSS from that part:

```
.wr-megamenu-container ul.wr-mega-menu {
z-index: 9999;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should try to reduce the padding of each menu element, this way:

```
.header-primary-nav .wr-mega-menu.nav-menu> li >a { padding: 0 8px;}
```

Then you will also need to change your menu `float` rule from right to left this way:

```
.logo-wrapper .header-primary-nav, .logo-wrapper .hgroup-sidebar { float: left; }
```

This should solve your issue…